# Text alignment R

Tags: r, right-align

I would like to reproduce this presentation:
[image]

This is my code but I get the text of the columns aligned on the left. Do you have an idea how to align it to the right?

```
cat("===========================================================\n \n") 
cat("\n Statistiques des variables vitesse_10km vitesse_21km \n") 
cat("----------------------------------------------------------- \n \n") 
cat("\t ", "\t ", "vitesse_10km", "\t ", "vitesse_21km", "\n")
cat("Moyenne   ", "\t ", mean10,  "\t ", "\t ", mean21, "\n")
cat("Ecart-type   ", "\t ", sd10, "\t ","\t ", sd21, "\n")
cat("Minimum  ", "\t ", min10, "\t ", "\t ", min21, "\n")
cat("Maximum  ", "\t ", max10, "\t ", max21, "\n")
cat("===========================================================\n \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *sprintf* to format numbers (or strings) with a fixed size filled up with leading spaces. Example:

```
> cat(sprintf("++% 8.2f++", 20))
++   20.00++
```